# Can the document desktop stacks be split for a specific file extension?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, desktop

I have documents I would like to have stacked
on my desktop.

Specifically, to group all files with a particular extension all together using Mojave's new Stacks feature.

Is there a way to register a new stacks kind?

Comment: Have a look at: [How to use Stacks on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT209101)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - Apple designed the default configuration but does allow you to stack on tags, which are user definable.

You could also make a smart folder to locate all the specific files you want, and then curate the tags easily, but not automatically out of the box.

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/355063/hold-for-beta-how-to-organize-your-desktop-with-stacks-on-macos-mojave/):

Here's how to use tags for custom desktop Finder stacks.

In the image below, you can see the option under `Group Stacks by -> Tags`.

Each of the files you want to put in this Stack must have the same Tag.  When you do this, macOS will create a custom Stack for you for all files that contain that Tag.

This is the only way that I'm aware to create a custom Stack.

[image: How to create custom Stacks using Tags]